# Why does my wallpaper change to the previous wallpaper I had while my computer is locked?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, desktop-customization

Windows XP SP 2

When my computer is locked, the wallpaper displayed on it is the previous one that I had put on there, but when it's not locked, the wallpaper goes back to my current one. How can I fix it so that it will display my current wallpaper when locked?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This Microsoft Support article describes the problem ("This behavior is by design")
[Previous Bitmap Image Displayed When Computer Is Locked](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/236369)
Read this article to understand how this problem occurs (normally when one was a bmp and the other a jpeg).

The solution given is as follows:

> To prevent this behavior from
>   occurring, clear the previous
>   wallpaper by clicking **None** in the
>   **Select a background picture or HTML
>   document as wallpaper box**, and then
>   clicking **Apply**. Then, select the
>   Active Desktop image you want to use.
>   When the computer is locked, the
>   computer will display the background
>   color and no previous images.

Comment: Ah good thinking, hadn't thought about the way Windows XP sets a JPEG desktop background.

Comment: Ok, I did that, but now how do I get it to display my current BG?

Comment: Apparently, you must set it again.

Comment: This problem only happened to me when I set my wallpaper to a PNG.  I converted to a JPG and now all is well.

Comment: Conclusion: It seems like Microsoft's implementation of PNG is to avoided.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that sometime in the past you have used a utility to copy your user account wallpaper settings to the "Default" Login/Lock account. You can use [TweakUI](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/Downloads/powertoys/Xppowertoys.mspx) to do this again. You can also make these changes directly in the registry at the following key.

```
HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Desktop
```

Comment: Is there any other way? This is happening on my work computer and I'm not allowed to install most applications or make registry changes.